# How to remove duplicate (user-defined classes) entries that both Lists have in common?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

Odd that there isn't more on this.

**Short Version**

ListA has some elements that ListB has, some not.
ListB has some elements that ListA has, some not. 
...in fact, the vast majority are dupes.

note: The elements are not common types, but from a Class I made... (LINQ Intersect seems to only work on known types-see update below)

How to delete the entries in *both Lists* that they *have in common*?

**Long Version**

-A device has ListA items on it, and I want to sync it with ListB's items. I do not want to delete & make new. That is not a possible choice.

-To sync the Lists, I will:

first:

1. (?) remove any dupes between them (these entries are already sync'd,
   after all).
2. second: (easy) remove any ListA entries remaining (as they are not
   on ListB, or else they would have been deleted as a dupe).
3. third: (easy) add to ListA any entries left on ListB (the List we
   need to end up with on ListA).

**Discussion**

Now yes, I could simply iterate through each List manually, but the question has more to do with elegance & performance. Union just applies a sort of 'distinct' operation that leaves the dupes.

using VB and/or LINQ, but can convert from C#...

**UPDATE - LINQ Intersect does not like Custom/User types (classes):**

```
List1: ip: 85.94.160.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 35462368
List1: ip: 91.187.64.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 15720800
List1: ip: 109.111.96.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 27477092
List1: ip: 185.4.52.0 net: 255.255.252.0 hash: 19444704
List1: ip: 194.158.64.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 65489923

List2: ip: 85.94.160.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 45276315
List2: ip: 91.187.64.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 10391797
List2: ip: 109.111.96.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 29919882
List2: ip: 185.4.52.0 net: 255.255.252.0 hash: 13173532
List2: ip: 194.158.64.0 net: 255.255.224.0 hash: 65387957
```

(hash means the output of .GetHashCode() for each instance)

Can I *override* the comparator function that LINQ's Intersect is using? I didn't find much online about how LINQ's Intersect functions (what it uses to judge 'equality')...

---

For the VB.NET folks:

This is [user2321864](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321864/user2321864)'s solution, but in VB.NET:

```
Dim a = New List(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 6, 8}
Dim b = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}

'find items common in both lists
Dim dupes = a.Intersect(b).ToList()

'delete common items from both lists
a.RemoveAll(Function(x) dupes.Contains(x))
b.RemoveAll(Function(x) dupes.Contains(x))
```

Comment: All you need to do is override Equals and GetHashCode and you can verify that they'll have be considered equal based on values of the properties.  You can also create an implementation of IEqualityComparer for your POCOs which you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the final version that will do the trick. I just concat'd the IP & subnet for hashing so there would always be a consistent way. As long as you combine the elements you want to use for equality the same way that is consistent across use, you can use anything as your equality hash input.

The big take-away is that .GetHashCode and .Equals are related. That point is made in other posts here on SO. It's a wonderful thing to this programmer that we can override these functions to suit our custom objects!

It can be modified for any custom type in VB...

Thanks everyone!

```
Public Class NetworkEntry
    [...]
    '
    ' override base functions for proper .Equals(x) operation
    '
    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim concat As String = Me.HostAddress.ToString & Me.SubnetAddress.ToString
        Return concat.GetHashCode
    End Function
    '
    Public Overloads Function Equals(obj As NetworkObject) As Boolean
        Dim equal As Boolean = False
        If (Me.HostAddress.ToString = obj.HostAddress.ToString) And
            (Me.SubnetAddress.ToString = obj.SubnetAddress.ToString) Then
                equal = True
        End If
        Return equal
    End Function
    [...]
End Class
```

Thanks to everyone for their input!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ Intersect will give you the common entries in both lists

```
var a = new List<int>{2,4,6,8};
var b = new List<int>{1,2,3,5,7};

//find items common in both lists
var dupes = a.Intersect(b).ToList();

//delete common items from both lists
a.RemoveAll(x => dupes.Contains(x));
b.RemoveAll(x => dupes.Contains(x));
```

Comment: +user2321864 Thanks for this. The entries in ListA are on a router as blocked networks, which is why I couldn't just whack them all on-device & re-insert them... :)

Comment: You could probably also use `a.Except(b)` and `b.Except(a)`

Comment: Well, this solution ends up being great if you use common types. In my case, the lists (although they have the same exact item types), have different items when I do a GetHashCode... I'll elaborate above in another update...

Answer (score -1):

After your sort both lists (takes O[n log n] + O[m log m]) you can solve this problem in O(max(n,m)) by simply iterating through both lists.

Comment: I know I, at least, would be able to give you more feedback if there was an example of how I'd go about doing what you suggest. :)

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a bit abstract, but essentially there are many ways to do this. My goal was to explain it in a generic way, with time complexity as the main concern, since you were looking for performance. Linq probably does the same in the back-end of the Intersect extension method (you could check through ILSpy or a similar decompiler).